# Как работать с таблицей многие к многим?

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

База для фирмы сборки компьютеров. Есть 5 таблиц

```
Sotrs(Сотрудник собирающий ПК):
    SotrID
    FIO

Clients(Клиенты):
    ClientID
    FIO

Components(Компоненты):
    ComponentID
    ComponentName
    Price

Assemblage(сама сборка):
    AssembID
    ClientID
    SotrID

Relations(таблица связей компонента и сборки):
    RelationID
    AssembID
    ComponentID
```

Пытаюсь запросом получить данные в таком формате:

```
    AssembID
    ClientFIO
    SotrFIO
    AllComponentPrice
```

Получилась такая ерунда:

```
SELECT assemblage.AssembID as "ID", clients.FIO as "ClientFIO", sotrs.FIO as "SotrFIO", SUM(SELECT "price" FROM (SELECT "assembID" FROM "assemblage" LEFT JOIN "relations" GROUP BY "AssembID")) as "FullPrice"
FROM "assemblage"
    LEFT JOIN "clients" ON "assemblage"."ClientID"="clients"."ClientID"
    LEFT JOIN "sotrs" ON "assemblage"."SotrID"="sotrs"."SotrID"
GROUP BY "assemblage"."AssembID"
```

Не могу понять, как работать с таблицей многие к многим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> не могу понять как работать с таблицей многие к многим

Просто продолжай добавлять `JOIN`'ы пока таблицы не кончаться:

```
SELECT 
  assemblage.AssembID as "ID",
  clients.FIO as "ClientFIO",
  sotrs.FIO as "SotrFIO",
  SUM(price) as "FullPrice"
FROM "assemblage"
    LEFT JOIN "clients" ON "assemblage"."ClientID"="clients"."ClientID"
    LEFT JOIN "sotrs" ON "assemblage"."SotrID"="sotrs"."SotrID"
    JOIN Relations ON assemblage.AssembID = Relations.AssembID
    JOIN Components  ON Relations.ComponentID = Components.ComponentID
GROUP BY "assemblage"."AssembID"
```

Если есть желание сделать именно с подзапросом, то как-то так (непроверенно):

```
SELECT 
  assemblage.AssembID as "ID",
  clients.FIO as "ClientFIO",
  sotrs.FIO as "SotrFIO",
  ( SELECT SUM("price")
    FROM "relations" 
    LEFT JOIN "Components" ON relations.ComponentID = Components.ComponentID
    WHERE relations.AssembID = ID
    GROUP BY "AssembID"
  ) AS "FullPrice"
FROM "assemblage"
    LEFT JOIN "clients" ON "assemblage"."ClientID"="clients"."ClientID"
    LEFT JOIN "sotrs" ON "assemblage"."SotrID"="sotrs"."SotrID"
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Пока изучаю эти запросы, хочу узнать, а какой из этих двух запросов более корректный? В плане оптимизации наверно одинаково работают?

Comment: @Den, почти наверняка планировщик составит одинаковые планы для запросов, чтобы удостовериться смотри `EXPLAIN`, так что в плане производитаельности должны быть абсолютно идентичны... в остальном обычно `JOIN` проще читается и ближе к тому как работает запрос, так что я бы остановился на нём.